# Display NETSH Command

Tags: variables, findstr, netsh, ssid

I have this NETSH command (below) set to a variable, %connectionname% and i need to use it later to disconnect from the internet, and then again later to reconnect again to the internet.

```
set %connectionname%=NETSH WLAN SHOW INTERFACE | findstr /r "^....SSID"`
```

it shows that the variable is blank after disconnecting from the internet, and i am not sure why,
Could someone help me figure out why this isnt displaying?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set a variable to the output of a command using that syntax. You should use the FOR /F command, enclosing the command in single quotes within the IN() clause to signal FOR that you want to execute a command.

I'm assuming you want the value in your variable, and not the SSID label. So you want to set the FOR /F delimiters to colon and space, and set the token to 2. Also, you only enclose a variable name in percents when you want to expand the value. You do not use percents when you want to set the variable.

Here is the complete command that can be run from the command line:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=: " %A in ('netsh wlan show interface ^| findstr "^....SSID"') do set "connectionname=%A"
```

If you want to include the command in a batch file, then you must double the percents: `%A`  becomes `%%A`.

Type `HELP FOR` or `FOR /?` from the command prompt for more information about how to use FOR /F.

Comment: Thanks im still newb status on anything advanced so thanks for the help and thanks i didnt know that you could not set a variable to the output of a command using that syntax so thanks.

Comment: Hey i just tested the code and it found my exact SSID and set it to the variable.Now i can auto-disconnect and reconnect from the internet in my batch, perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: @CodeKeyer - Don't forget to accept a good answer that solves your problem. Click on the check mark near the upper left corner of the answer. That action lets others know your question has been answered, it grants you 2 reputation points, and grants the answer poster 15 rep points. Only one question can be accepted per answer. Once you reach 15 rep points, you gain the privilege to vote up any number of questions and answers. A question up vote grants 5 points to the questioner, and an answer up vote grants 10 rep points. You can up vote as many answers as you find useful.